# How to enable modifier keys mapping for bluetooth 4.0 keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

[image]

In macOS 10.13.6, when I use a bluetooth 4.0 keyboards the modifier keys mapping seems to be missing (keyboard not showing up). After I switch the keyboard to bluetooth 3.0 mode it shows up.

Does it mean that macOS doesn't fully support bluetooth 4.0 keyboards?

Comment: What brand/model keyboard are you referring to?

Comment: @TomGewecke Rapoo Bluetooth 4.0 Keyboard

Comment: Doesn't your keyboard have a model number?  Or provide the url for purchasing it.

Comment: How is the model number important?! The question is about the OS and the OS does not know all keyboard models on the planet.

Comment: I use keyboard KeyCool KC84 Hero with BT 4.0 has the same problem, but the `select keyboard` option will be showed if I use cable.

Comment: has anyone figured out a fix or work around for this problem